# Unseemly spaces at start of lines

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am making solutions to a problem with many parts.  I want the parts to be indented by `\qquad`.  The first line is indented about twice as much as the other lines, but I used the commands `\noindent \qquad`.  I also have the same extra spaces in the second lines to the answers to c.) and d.).  (I want these second lines to align with the start of the first lines of c.) and d.).  I use the `\hphantom` command.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}


\noindent \qquad a.) The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. \\
\qquad b.) $y = 0$ is the equation of the asymptote to the graph of $f$. \\
\qquad c.) The intervals on which $f$ is increasing are $[-1, \, 0]$ and $[1, \, \infty)$, and the \\
\noindent \hphantom{\qquad c.) }intervals on which $f$ is decreasing are $(-\infty, \, -1]$ and $[0, 1]$. \\
\qquad d.) The intervals on which $f$ is concave up are $(-1.5, \, -0.5)$ and $(0.5, \, 1.5)$, and \\
\noindent \hphantom{\qquad d.) }the intervals on which  $f$ is concave down are $(-\infty, \, -1.5)$ and $(1.5, \, \infty)$. \\
\qquad e.) The coordinates of the critical points of $f$ are $(1, \, -1.75)$, $(0, \, 0)$, and $(1, -1.75)$. \\
\qquad f.) The coordinates of the inflection points of $f$ are $(-1.5, \, -1.25)$ and $(1.5, \, -1.25)$. \\
\qquad g.) $f > 0$ on $\emptyset$. \\
\qquad h.) $f^{\prime} > 0$ on $(-1, \, 0) \cup (1, \, \infty)$. \\
\qquad i.) $f^{\prime\prime} > 0$ on $(-1.5, \, -0.5) \cup (0.5, \, 1.5)$.
\vskip0.25in


\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use a list? it's almost never necessary to number and align things by hand like this, `\noindent` or `\\ ` in the body of a document is almost always a sign that something is wrong/

Comment: @David Carlisle I agree that there are environments for this.  I was using code provided by someone.  I thought that it would be little effort to get the right formatting with `\noindent` and `\qquad`.  I like the code that Andrew provided.  Can you tell me how my code could not be compiled correctly?

Comment: It's hard to know where to start:-) `\noindent` has no effect after `\\ ` only at the start of a paragraph, there is no alignment of the `)` because the letters have different widths, only the first `\qquad` makes any space (the others make space at the start of a line where space is discarded. ...

Comment: OK since you made same comment on Andrews answer I'll step though the original line by line in my answer.

Comment: @David Carlisle  What do you mean by "step though."

Comment: I just updated my answer with line by line comments explaining why the code in the question doesn't work as you hoped (that's what I meant by stepping through here)

Comment: @David Carlisle  You answer all my questions about my code not giving me what I wanted except for the extra space that I got in the second line to the answer to c.).  I will use the enumerate environment ... but I am curious.

Comment: I added a note about that (in italics) under that line in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.)}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. 
\item $y = 0$ is the equation of the asymptote to the graph of $f$. 
\item The intervals on which $f$ is increasing are $[-1, \, 0]$ and $[1, \, \infty)$, and the 
intervals on which $f$ is decreasing are $(-\infty, \, -1]$ and $[0, 1]$. 
\item The intervals on which $f$ is concave up are $(-1.5, \, -0.5)$ and $(0.5, \, 1.5)$, and 
 the intervals on which  $f$ is concave down are $(-\infty, \, -1.5)$ and $(1.5, \, \infty)$.
\item The coordinates of the critical points of $f$ are $(1, \, -1.75)$, $(0, \, 0)$, and $(1, -1.75)$. 
\item The coordinates of the inflection points of $f$ are $(-1.5, \, -1.25)$ and $(1.5, \, -1.25)$. 
\item $f > 0$ on $\emptyset$. 
\item $f' > 0$ on $(-1, \, 0) \cup (1, \, \infty)$. 
\item f'' > 0$ on $(-1.5, \, -0.5) \cup (0.5, \, 1.5)$.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

To see what's wrong with the original:

```
\noindent \qquad a.) The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. \\
```

`\noindent` starts the paragraph, so then `\qquad` ads 2em of space then you get `a.`
and a bracket positioned depending on the width of `a`

```
\qquad b.) $y = 0$ is the equation of the asymptote to the graph of $f$. \\
```

The preceding `\\` doesn't start a paragraph, just encourages a linebreak, spaces after linebreaks are discarded as part of tex's paragraph justification, so `\qquad` does nothing. Which is why the first line (only) seems indented. the `)` is then positioned depending on the width of `b` which is different to that of `a`.

```
\qquad c.) The intervals on which $f$ is increasing are $[-1, \, 0]$ and $[1, \, \infty)$, and the \\
```

as above

```
\noindent \hphantom{\qquad c.) }intervals on which $f$ is decreasing are $(-\infty, \, -1]$ and $[0, 1]$. \\
```

`\noindent` does nothing in this position,  the alignment is also off because the space after the `)` in the phantom will always be set at its natural size, but the spaces in the line above are shrunk to fit the line. *Note that while the other `\qquad` are discarded, the one here is inside a phantom box not at the start of line, so is not discarded so this line is indented by `\qquad`.*

```
\qquad d.) The intervals on which $f$ is concave up are $(-1.5, \, -0.5)$ and $(0.5, \, 1.5)$, and \\
```

as above.....

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'd worked out what was happening but not why.

Comment: @David Carlisle  Yes, that more careful explanation clarifies some commands for me.  When my computer compiled the code, I got what looked like two `\qquad` spaces to start the second lines in the answers to c.) and to d.).  Why would LaTeX do that?

Comment: @Adelyn no you get 1 on those lines (as the qquad is inside a box)  and none on the others (as the space is discarded)

Comment: @David Carlisle  Some of the mathematical expressions - like intervals - make some of the lines go past the right margin. I prefer to have a ragged right margin. How do I get that?

Comment: @Adelyn stick `\raggedright` after `\begin{enumerate}` (or I suspect `enumitem` has a key for that in its `[...]` argument if you go the `enumitem` way).

Comment: @David Carlisle  I am using the enumerate environment.  It appears that `\raggedright` is not an optional command for it.

Comment: @Adelyn if you use the environment as above then  meant `\begin{enumerate}\raggedright`

Comment: @David Carlisle  I had coded `\begin{enumerate}[\raggedright]`.  The mistake was putting `\raggedright` as an optional specification for the enumerate environment.

Answer (score 3):

As David says above you are much better off using a list and letting LaTeX take care of the formatting and numbering. Doing it this way is easier, both to read and to write and, the layout is automatically uniform and easy to change.

For this I would use the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to obtain

[image]

using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.)]
\item The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$.
\item $y = 0$ is the equation of the asymptote to the graph of $f$.
\item The intervals on which $f$ is increasing are $[-1, \, 0]$ and $[1, \, \infty)$, and the
intervals on which $f$ is decreasing are $(-\infty, \, -1]$ and $[0, 1]$.
\item The intervals on which $f$ is concave up are $(-1.5, \, -0.5)$ and $(0.5, \, 1.5)$, and
the intervals on which  $f$ is concave down are $(-\infty, \, -1.5)$ and $(1.5, \, \infty)$.
\item The coordinates of the critical points of $f$ are $(1, \, -1.75)$, $(0, \, 0)$, and $(1, -1.75)$.
\item The coordinates of the inflection points of $f$ are $(-1.5, \, -1.25)$ and $(1.5, \, -1.25)$.
\item $f > 0$ on $\emptyset$.
\item $f' > 0$ on $(-1, \, 0) \cup (1, \, \infty)$.
\item $f'' > 0$ on $(-1.5, \, -0.5) \cup (0.5, \, 1.5)$.
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

As to what is happening with your code. The problem is that `\qquad` has no effect after `\\`. This is a little surprising to me, and I didn't expect it, but you can see this by considering the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\parskip=1em
\begin{document}
  1. Normal line without \verb|\noindent|

  \noindent 2. Normal line with \verb|\noindent|

  \qquad 3. Normal line with \verb|\qquad|

  4. Normal line ending with \verb|\\|\\
  \qquad 5. Normal line with \verb|\qquad|
\end{document}
```

I expected to see all but line 2 indented (lines 1 and 4 by `\parindent` and lines 3 and 5 by `\qquad`). however, line 5 is NOT indented:

[image]

As David explains properly, "spaces after linebreaks are discarded". If you really want a space after a `\\` you can use `\hspace*{2em}`.

Comment: Your code gives me the formatting that I want.  Thanks.  Why does `LaTeX` not compile my code correctly?

Comment: There's no need for `\,` after commas in math, that space is added by default; `f^{\prime\prime}` is the exact same as `f''`.

Comment: @Adelyn Most of your lines are NOT being indented. There are three exceptions: the first line, labelled `(a)`, and the second lines for `(c)` and `(d)`. I guess that `\qquad` has no effect after `\\`. I am not sure why this is, and it is not what I expected, but this is what is happening. I'll add some details.

Comment: @Adelyn I added some notes

Comment: @Andrew  Now, I have one comment on using the enumerate environment. Some of the mathematical expressions - like intervals - make the lines go past the right margin. I prefer to have a ragged right margin.  How do I get that?

Comment: @Adelyn Put `\raggedright` at the top of your document -- or inside the `enumerate` environment to make ragged right "local" to that environment. Btw, you should give David the tick as he explained the problem with your code.

Comment: @Andrew: Don't you think adding the `align=left` option to enumerate would make the list look better?

Comment: @Bernard   I just tried `align=left` option.  It leaves an unseemly space between the right parenthesis and the explanation.

Comment: @Adelyn: You're right. If you also add `labelsep=-0.1em` it looks much better, in my opinion.